# SVD decomposition of orthonormal matrix Issue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, svd

If i have a matrix $E \in \Re^{nxm}$ with orthonormal columns (e.g $E^TE = I_m$) then how to demonstrate (through Singular Value decomposition on $E$) that :

$I_n-EE^T = U(I_n -\Sigma\Sigma^T)U^T$ ?

PS : through SVD i establish the relation : $E^TE = VV^T$

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the SVD: $E=U\Sigma V$ then

\begin{align}
I_n-EE^T 
&=I_n-U\Sigma V(U\Sigma V)^T\\
&=I_n-U\Sigma (VV^T)\Sigma^TU^T\\
&=UI_nU^T-U\Sigma (VV^T)\Sigma^TU^T\\
&= U(I_n -\Sigma\Sigma^T)U^T
\end{align}

Comment: Yes thanks for the help !

Comment: @Sam: you are welcome!